# How to get DENSE_RANK() results with RANK() in sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Category ID     Rank_Number     Rank_Number1
AA      x   1           1
AA      x   1           1
AA      x   1           1
AA      y   4           2
AA      y   4           2
AA      y   4           2
AA      z   7           3
AA      z   7           3
AA      z   7           3
```

I use SQL 2008 so I can’t use DENSE_RANK().  I’m using the following code, which gives me the Rank_Number. (not the way I want)

```
Select *,  RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY ID)    AS Rank_Number
```

My question:

How can I get the results like in Rank_Number1?

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` exists since SQL Server 2005. Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK()` exists since SQL Server 2005:

```
Select *,  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY ID)    
from table1
AS Rank_Number
```

Comment: Oops.. Sorry. My mistake. It works now !! Thank You. I tried it before and got an error. Since I have never used DENSE_RANK() before, I thought it's not available in 2008. All good now.